# ¿Como puedo hacer que varios Hilos dibujen varios JLabel?

Tags: java

Mi profe me dejo hacer un programa donde se le pida al usuario un dato de entrada y de acuerdo a ese dato generar "N" agentes (Hilos) y que cada agente aparezca de manera aleatoria en una ventana. Después de que aparezcan, los agentes deberán de moverse de manera aleatoria ya sea arriba, abajo, izquierda o derecha. Mi problema está en que a la hora de mandar a llamar a la función `mover` solo 1 agente(Hilo) es el que se mueve; los demás agentes se quedan estáticos. Mis agentes los estoy imprimiendo en JLabel. Aquí les dejo el código a ver si alguien puede ayudarme a solucionar ese problema.

```
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.*;
public class Ventana extends JFrame implements Runnable{

   JLabel label1;


   public Ventana() {

      int cantidad=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Numero de agentes?: "));
      Thread hilo[]= new Thread[cantidad];
       for(int i=0;i<cantidad;i++) {
          hilo= new Thread(this);
          hilo.start();
       }
    }

   public void agregalabel(int x1,int y1) {

      setLayout(null);
        label1=new JLabel("(*)");
        label1.setBounds(x1,y1,x1,y1);
        add(label1);
   } 

   public void mover(int x1,int y1) {
      int dec;
      while(true) {
      dec = (int)(Math.random()*3)+1;

      switch(dec) {
      case 1:
          System.out.println(dec);
         while(x1<getWidth()-30){
         x1=x1+10;
         label1.setBounds(x1,y1,x1,y1);
           try {
              Thread.sleep(500);
           }catch(Exception e) {

           }
         }
              break;

      case 2:
         System.out.println(dec);
         while(x1>20){
            x1=x1-10;
            label1.setBounds(x1,y1,x1,y1);
            try {
                 Thread.sleep(500);
              }catch(Exception e) {

              }
            }
             break;
      case '3':
          System.out.println("3");
            while(y1<getHeight()-30){
            y1=y1+10;
            label1.setBounds(x1,y1,x1,y1);
              try {
                 Thread.sleep(500);
              }catch(Exception e) {

              }
            }
             break;
      case '4':
             break;

      }
      }
   }

    public static void main(String[] ar) {
        Ventana formulario1=new Ventana();
        formulario1.setBounds(0,0,1500,400);
       //formulario1.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
       // formulario1.setSize(1300,600);
        formulario1.setResizable(true);
        formulario1.setVisible(true);
    }
    int x1,y1;
   @Override
   public void run() {

      try {
         x1= (int)(Math.random()*500)+300;
         y1= (int)(Math.random()*100)+301;

         agregalabel(x1,y1);
         mover(x1,y1);
         System.out.println("X: "+x1+"Y: "+y1);
         Thread.sleep(1000);
      }catch(Exception e) {

      }

      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que todos los hilos comparten el mismo objeto y, por tanto, el mismo atributo `JLabel label1;`: Todos los hilos están moviendo el mismo `JLabel`, que es el último que se añadió.

Answer (score 1):

Como bien dice @pablo-lozano, estás compartiendo el `Label` entre hilos. Además tienes algún otro fallo:

- **Array de hilos**: Estás declarando un array de `Thread` pero luego intentas asignarle un hilo sin acceder al índice del array. Esto no debería ni compilarte

  ```
  Thread hilo[] = new Thread[cantidad];
   for (int i = 0; i < cantidad; i++) {
    hilo = new Thread(this, "Hilo n: " + i);
    hilo.start();
    System.out.println(hilo[i].getName());
  }
  ```
- **Valores x1, y1**: Al igual que el `JLabel` los tienes declarados fuera del `run`, por lo que en el primer hilo no, pero en el resto te asignará a todos los mismos valores (superponiéndose las etiquetas)

Te dejo un ejemplo rápido de cómo tendrías que hacer (el `JLabel` se crea en el run y se pasa como argumento a los métodos que lo modifican)

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package ventana;

import javax.swing.*;

/**
 *
 * @author fjlabiano
 */
public class Ventana extends JFrame implements Runnable {
public Ventana() {

    int cantidad = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Numero de agentes?: "));
    Thread hilo[] = new Thread[cantidad];
    for (int i = 0; i < cantidad; i++) {
        hilo[i] = new Thread(this, "Hilo n: " + i);
        hilo[i].start();
        System.out.println(hilo[i].getName());
    }
}

public void agregalabel(int x1, int y1, JLabel label1) {

    setLayout(null);
    label1.setBounds(x1, y1, x1, y1);
    add(label1);
}

public void mover(int x1, int y1, JLabel label1) {
    int dec;
    while (true) {
        dec = (int) (Math.random() * 3) + 1;
        System.out.println("X: " + x1 + "Y: " + y1);
        switch (dec) {
            case 1:
                while (x1 < getWidth() - 30) {
                    x1 = x1 + 100;
                    label1.setBounds(x1, y1, x1, y1);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                }
                break;

            case 2:
                while (x1 > 20) {
                    x1 = x1 - 100;
                    label1.setBounds(x1, y1, x1, y1);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                }
                break;
            case '3':
                while (y1 < getHeight() - 30) {
                    y1 = y1 + 100;
                    label1.setBounds(x1, y1, x1, y1);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                }
                break;
            case '4':
                break;

        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] ar) {
    Ventana formulario1 = new Ventana();
    formulario1.setBounds(0, 0, 1800, 800);
    //formulario1.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    // formulario1.setSize(1300,600);
    formulario1.setResizable(true);
    formulario1.setVisible(true);
}

@Override
public void run() {
    int x1, y1;
    try {
        x1 = (int) (Math.random() * 500) + 500;
        y1 = (int) (Math.random() * 100) + 301;
        JLabel label1 = new JLabel("(*)");
        agregalabel(x1, y1, label1);
        System.out.println("Label agregado");
        mover(x1, y1, label1);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
}
```